# convert image to resp(<class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>) type in Django

Tags: python, django, image, numpy, binary

previous code :

```
 
resp = requests.get(IMAGE_API, params={'empid': employee_id}, stream=True).raw
return resp
```

resp type is <class 'urllib3.response.HTTPResponse'>

now i want to resize this image and return in 'resp form'. How to do it?

```
image = np.asarray(bytearray(resp.read()), dtype="uint8")       
image = cv2.imdecode(image, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
imageResized =  cv2.resize(image, (0,0) , fx = ratio, fy = ratio )
```

imageResized type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

how can i convert imageResized to 'resp' type ?

Comment: How it is related to Django ?